# unnecessary debug info in rails view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

In my rails app I'm displaying some posts using nested loops. In development mode, after each loop completes the post objects are dumped in plain text in sequence. So it looks like this:[image]

It's unnecessary and kind of obnoxious. What causes this behavior and how do disable it? Edit: here is the loop:

```
= @posts.each do |post|
  .post
    %p= post.text
    .replies
      = if post.children != 0
        = link_to "#{post.children} replies", '#',:toggled=>'no',:id=>"parent#{post.id}",:class=>"viewreplies",:rel=>post.children
      %a.reply{:href => '#',:id => "reply#{post.id}",:rel => "thread#{post.thread}",:toggled=>'no' } Reply
  %form{:method=>:post, :action => '/create', :class => 'replyform' }
    = token_tag
  %div{:id=>"replies#{post.id}"}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not the case by default, you're dumping Post objects in there explicitly in some place.

My guess is you have additional `=` sign in `<% @posts.each do |post| %>` (i.e., you use `<%= ... %>`). `each` method returns collection itself (for possible chaining, like in jquery) and there's little point in printing it.

If you have any confusion about the difference,
`<% .. %>` means 'execute this'
`<%= .. %>` means 'execute this and print return value on the page'

Comment: @herpderp I don't use haml, but I suspect `=` sign there has the same meaning as in rails. Tried removing it? Also, [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haml) features an 'each' example without it.

Comment: = is necessary in haml, it denotes ruby code. without it haml treats the code as plain text. using - works too, but it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: OH WAIT, I had only changed = to - in the original loop in my index.html.haml file, not in the partial that contained the nested loops. everything's fine now, that solved it.

Comment: @herpderp You can check [this section](http://haml-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.HAML_REFERENCE.html#ruby_evaluation) in haml docs about '=', '-' and similar stuff. And the whole documentation isn't that long, might be worth reading.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the =@post use -@post